# R program - install.packages

Tags: r, install.packages

when I'm trying to install.packages in R program I always face with this Error:

```
package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i,
c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package
called ‘colorspace’
```

how can I fix?

I just tried to install packages like "pheatmap" and "ggplot2"
when I use the code: `library("pheatmap")`, I face this error.

Comment: Hi Ehsan, welcome to Stack Overflow. Try this: `install.packages("colorspace")` and then `library(colorspace)` and then try again. `R` is telling you that you are missing a common package (colorspace), and some of the other packages that you are using requires this package.

Comment: After installing colorspace, there's no need to call `library(colorspace)` before installing `pheatmap`.